# Where can I find vue cli 2 docs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I need different build modes for my vue cli 2 application and I've checked multiple resources but all of them are for vue cli 3. Then I tried to find docs for vue cli 2 but I wasn't able to find them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one for v2 related docs:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/v2#vue-cli--